# How to filter data with the highest number

Tags: text-processing, awk, text-editor, cut-command

I have thousands data like this:

```
abc_1
abc_2
abc_3
abc_4
def_1
def_2
def_3
ghi_1
ghi_2
```

I want to filter it to get only data with the highest number which is `abc_4, def_3, ghi_2`.

How I can get it?

Answer (score 3):

Using awk, as implied by your tags:

```
$ awk -F_ '
    {m[$1] = $2 > m[$1] ? $2 : m[$1]} 
    END {OFS = FS; for(x in m) print x, m[x]}
  ' file | sort
abc_4
def_3
ghi_2
```

If you have GNU awk > 4.0 you can do the sorting internally

```
$ awk -F_ '
    {m[$1] = $2 > m[$1] ? $2 : m[$1]} 
    END {
      OFS = FS; PROCINFO["sorted_in"] = "@ind_str_asc"; 
      for(x in m) print x, m[x]
    }
  ' file
abc_4
def_3
ghi_2
```

---

Alternatively, if you have [Miller](https://johnkerl.org/miller/doc/) you can do a groupwise max using the `stat1` verb:

```
$ mlr --nidx --fs _ stats1 -a max -f 2 -g 1 file
abc_4
def_3
ghi_2
```

or with [GNU datamash](https://www.gnu.org/software/datamash/)

```
$ datamash -t_ groupby 1 max 2 < file
abc_4
def_3
ghi_2
```

or for your specific input, assuming that the prefix strings are fixed length, using standard utilities `sort` and `uniq`:

```
$ sort -t_ -k1,1 -k2,2nr file | uniq -w4
abc_4
def_3
ghi_2
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. All command that you mentioned works well. But, how if in my data exists `jkl_1` is the highest number for `jkl`. Is that command still working? Thank you

Comment: @Lulu'Nisrina I can't see any reason why any of the commands I suggested would not work in that case - can you? did you try it?

Comment: I already tried it, and it's works well. Thank you